# AWS RDS convertible RIs do not exist, so how can I gauge whether my instance is enough before I commit for a year?

Tags: amazon-rds

I just migrated my small PostgreSQL database to AWS RDS, and I used a `db.m4.large` instance class.

For the first 12 hours I found the database to be performant, and here's some key metrics:

- CPU utilization around 15%
- DB connections around 20
- Freeable memory around 5 GB
- Write IOPS around 5/s, with spikes of 10-15/s
- Read IOPS around 0.4/s
- Queue depth around 0.015

It looks like to me that I'm well within the limits of this instance class.

My website is very stable and never has significant spikes. The growth is limited and I don't expect that traffic will increase more than 30-50% in a year.

Do you think it's safe to commit to a Reserved Instance in size `db.m4.large`?